# How can I convert decimal value 20.00 to 2000 using replace [Visual Basic 2010]?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I convert a decimal value that end with X0.00  to  X000?

Here are the other sample values and their output and remarks.

```
'value              output      remarks

    'num1 = 50.45        5045       Correct

    'num2 = 34.50        3450       Correct

    'num3 = 20.00         20         Wrong



    Dim Num As Double = 10.0
    Dim testing As String = Replace(Replace(FormatNumber(Num), "0.00", "0"), ".", "")

    MessageBox.Show(testing)
```

The Value of Num3 should be "2000".
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Dim testing As String = Num3.ToString("#.00").Replace(".","")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me :) .
By the way, I remove the excess  ")" to run the program.